# Yocto build for i.MX8QM is not booting

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot, bsp

I have built an image for the TQ Systems STKa8x Evaluation board with an i.MX8 QuadMax using the yocto project. The resulting image does not boot on the device. Can anyone help me interpret the warnings and errors occuring in the serial console output when trying to boot?

[image]

I think the the machine configuration might be wrong? The device hardware is ok, becaus the device boots using the included sd card.

Comment: Did you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before using this site? DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was caused by the SD card. I have used this SD card https://de.transcend-info.com/embedded/product/embedded-memory-cards/usd230i. Using another one solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you flash your Yocto image in your emmc or SDcard ? Here it seams that there is no partition table in your emmc which is  normally embedded inside Linux image. It is more likely that the flash did not succeed.

Plus you can see warning from u-boot that he cannot load the device tree. Check your repository build/tmp/deploy/image/machine/*.dtb

You should also check if your linux image and device tree is flashed in the correct address.

Comment: I've flashed the image in the SD card.

Comment: Line 3 of your screenshot "trying to boot from MMC2". Your device is not even trying to boot from sdcard. Check u-boot arguments

Comment: When your "answer" begins with a question, then it probably should be a comment.